# Pandas groupby + Numpy median: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to get the aggregate column-wise median of a series of arrays. For example:

```py
a = np.array([[1,9,3],[1,1,1],[8,5,4]])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a"])
df["a"] = list(a)
df["b"] = [1,1,2]
A = df.groupby("b")["a"].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x, axis=0))
print(A)
B = df.groupby("b")["a"].apply(lambda x: np.median(x, axis=0))
print(B)
```

Getting the mean works fine, but the median gives the error

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @mapf What does this mean?

Comment: In general, it is not a good idea to store these Python objects (lists, dicts etc.) in DataFrames because they are not really supported and you can get these kinds of bugs. This one is because numpy doesn't know how to take the median of an array of lists. If you convert it to a 2d array it should work (i.e. `df.groupby("b")["a"].apply(lambda x: np.median(np.array(x.tolist()), axis=0))`)

Comment: The first group is a 2 row Series, which when converted to numpy array is `array([array([1, 9, 3]), array([1, 1, 1])], dtype=object)`.  That's what `np.median` can't handle.

Answer (score 2):

`np.mean` is supported by numpy and pandas explicitly. Numpy mean will check if there is a `mean` attribute attached to the passed in structure ([numpy source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L3467-L3472)). If there is then the pandas `NDFrame.mean` function is used instead ([pandas source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L10825-L10826)).

However, `np.median` does not have the same such support in that `numpy` does not check if there is a `median` attribute it can use instead.

For this reason, the values will need to be converted to a valid 2d array first (either explicitly or implicitly by `np.median`).

```
B = df.groupby("b")["a"].apply(lambda x: np.median([*x], axis=0))
```

`B`:

```
b
1    [1.0, 5.0, 2.0]
2    [8.0, 5.0, 4.0]
Name: a, dtype: object
```

The following options would also work:

- `np.median(x.tolist(), axis=0)`
- `np.median(np.array([*x]), axis=0)`
- `np.median(np.array(x.tolist()), axis=0)`

Comment: Oh, I had tried np.array(x). What's the asterisk for?

Comment: It's unpacking into a list. You could also do `x.tolist()` or `np.array(x.tolist())` they all would work.